# why i get error when I trying to print quotation

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am learning c pragramming and when I try to print "Hello World" in quotation I get an error:

> id returned 1 exit status

Here is my code, I am using codeblock:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
  {
    printf("\"Hello World\" ");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error when building, or when running? If you get an error when building, then copy it all (in full and complete) as text, then edit your question to paste the error.

Comment: It works for me. How do you compile/run?

Comment: Also you might want to add a linebreak like this `"\"Hello World\"\n"`

Comment: Works here for me.

Comment: Maybe your native character encoding is incompatible somehow? I cannot reproduce the error. Try creating a `char` variable using the ASCII value:    `char quot = 0x22;printf("%cHello World%c", quot, quot);`

Answer (score 5):

```
error: id returned 1 exit status 
       ^
 should be "l", not "i"
```

I believe it's `ld`, not `id`. Code::Blocks uses GCC as compiler, and this is ***extremely*** likely that you **did not close the running program before trying to compile it again**.

Generally, `ld` (`ld.exe` on Windows) returns 1 when it can't access required files. This usually includes

- Can't find the object file to be linked (or `Access denied`)
- Can't find one or more symbols to link
- Can't open the executable for writing (or AD)

Your program looks completely fine, so the second point should not hit. In usual cases, it's impossible for `ld` to fail to open the object file (unless you have a faulty drive and a dirty filesystem), so the first point is also nearly impossible. Now we get to the third point.

A simple Google search gives a full page of the same answer: You forgot to close the program, before trying to re-compile.

That's all.

Comment: Great spot. And this is why retyping the error message (instead of copy&pasting) is a bad idea!

Comment: @Steve - FYI, In some environments, such as the Code::Blocks IDE, _copy/paste_ is not enabled from the Build messages output tab.  Unfortunate, but true.

Comment: @ryyker Good grief - _really_?

Comment: @Steve - Yes.  It is true not only for Code::Blocks, eg.  LabWindows/CVI from National Instruments does not. Of course, others do allow copying, such as Visual Studios.

Comment: I closed it and tried but same error again

Comment: here is a message from the logs    C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file C:\Users\samjo\Desktop\technion\c programming\hw1\Hw0qq2.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @SmerAbonwara Try deleting existing EXE file first.

Comment: Tried it same problem

Comment: The problem is when I give it another name it worked but I have to give it specific name to send it to my college

Comment: when you saying close the program before recompile do you mean to close the codeblog and then open it again? maybe I didnt understand you well